# Error while looping AJAX requests in Firefox

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm trying to create a piece of Javascript that connects to the server, receives a response and then automatically connects again.

```
<head>
    <title>tests</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/javascripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function requestData() {
            var oRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();

            oRequest.onreadystatechange = handleData;

            oRequest.open( 'GET', '/test.php', true );
            oRequest.send( null );
        }

        function handleData() {
            if( this.readyState == 4 ) {
                document.write( this.responseText );
                requestData();
            }
        }

        $(function(){

            requestData();

        });         
    </script>

</head>

<body>
</body>
```

The code above works fine in chrome but after two requests the script fails in Firefox with the following error...

requestData is not defined

Does anyone know why this is happening? The server is only responding with single digit numbers at the moment. (PS I know this doesn't work in IE, thats fine)

Thanks

Comment: I don't know why this is happening, but your script is very inefficient. Creating a new request object every time is a bit odd. Perhaps this is also the reason that this is happening, try rewriting it so that only the open/send part is in the requestData function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that two requests is as long as it takes Firefox to finish processing the document and close it. This means that when `document.write` is called again, it automatically calls `document.open` and trashes the existing document, including the scripts, so the function gets deleted.

Use [DOM manipulation](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/creating-and-modifying-html/) instead of `document.write`.

Comment: I just came back on to note that it only happens when I use document.write, if i console.log it's fine.

Answer (score -1):

If you use jquery, you should use $.ajax or something like that. It's easier to use and it works.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://my_url', 
    success: function (data) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://my_url_2', 
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            }
        })
    }
})
```